# What result does digital multimeter show when measuring filtered AC V? Is it Vavg or Vrms of the ripple voltage? What's the formula to calculate?

Tags: voltage, ac, multimeter, ripple

Can somebody tell me what result does multimeter show when measuring filtered AC V? Is it V avg or V rms of the voltage ripple? And what's the formulas to calculate this?

Comment: Depends on your meter.

Comment: What do you mean by filtered AC?

Comment: Read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is AC, most cheap meters will full wave rectify, average, then scale the result for the RMS of a sinewave, as that's cheapest. As the waveform changes from a sinewave, this method becomes increasingly inaccurate.

More expensive meters, ones that say RMS on the case, will give you you true RMS AC, up to a reasonable crest factor like 5:1 or something.

If by 'filtered AC' (which is an odd phrase to use), you mean a DC power supply that is smoothed, rectified AC, then you would measure that on a DC range, and it would read the average DC voltage.